# Ionic Build Failed Firebase-iid-interop.aar

Tags: ionic-framework, build, compilation

Since a few days, my application IONIC refuses to compile on ANDROID (I copy the code on a MAC, and there, miraculously, the compilation works without problem for iOS ... It is already that, but I need the compilation ANDROID ...).

I have not changed a single line of the program since the last compilation so I'm wondering if this does not come from an update.

When i do :

```
ionic codrova run android
```

or

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I've got this error :

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find firebase-iid-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/16.0.0/firebase-iid-interop-16.0.0.aar
> Could not find firebase-measurement-connector.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector/16.0.0/firebase-measurement-connector-16.0.0.aar
```

Comment: did you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: If you're still getting similar error, clear your gradle cache manually. (delete the .gradle/caches directory)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to have my project build ... But not really good, because it supposed to not be up-to-date ...

Go to your config.xml file and watch if this plugin is on the good version :

This version works for me :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" spec="^0.1.11" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="^3.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="^2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
<engine name="android" spec="~7.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically caused by the Jcenter repository in the Gradle file preceding the maven/google repository.

This has been fixed in cordova-android version 7.1.2.

To make your build work, all you need to is update the cordova-android version to 7.1.2 in config.xlm file and package.json.

in package.json:

```
"dependencies": { "cordova-android": "^7.1.2" }
```

and in config.xml:

```
<widget>
<engine name="android" spec="^7.1.2" />
</widget>
```

Also, note that whatever version of cordova-android in the package.json will override the version in config.xml

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14127